# SQL Select based on a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following is the structure of database table consisiting of foreign keys from two different tables.

```
         facilityID     roomID
            1           A.0.0.1
            2           A.0.0.1
            1           B.0.0.1
            2           B.0.0.1
            3           B.0.0.1
```

What I would like to do is perform a select statement something like

```
         Select roomID from room_facility where facilityID = '1' and facilityID = '3'
```

so that it gives me back a room which has both facilities combined in this case roomID "B.0.0.1" but the above SQL returns empty table. I have tried using 'OR' instead of 'AND' but but that gives me roomID "A.0.0.1" and "B.0.0.1" both which isn't what I am looking for because room "A.0.0.1" doesn't have facility "3".

I don't know if I am making any basic fundamental mistake over here but any guidance would be very helpful whether it is with SQL, a way to do it in SQL Server Stored Procedure or redesigin of the table's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `where` clause is evaluated for every row.  No row can satisfy `facilityID = '1'` and `facilityID = '3'` at the same time.

One approach is a group by.  You can use `count(distinct facilityID)` to ensure both rooms are found:

```
select  roomID
from    room_facility
where   facilityID in ('1','3')
group by
        roomID
having  count(distinct facilityID) = 2
```

Comment: Hi Andomar, the above SQL does the job for me. It was just what I was looking for. I am still trying grasp how it works though starting from the 'group by' clause. Anyway I probably a bit of googling might help me understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) problem.

```
SELECT roomID
FROM   room_facility
WHERE  facilityID IN ( '1', '3' )
GROUP  BY roomID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  /*Assuming facilityID,roomID is a composite PK*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the link Martin. I will definitely go through it.